# Server Client Authentication

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I`m trying to make a program in which the Server asks the client the password and if wrong sends a message but the problem is

I`m not able to make the BufferedReader wait till the Client has Entered a Password

After the Message "Enter Password"
is displayed I want the client to enter the password and carry out his operation but I`m not able to make BufferedReader  wait till the client sends any valid data in the stream

```
**Client**
package FTP;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class Client{
    String input,output,str;
    Socket s;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter pw;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    Thread read=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
        try{
            while(true){
             input=br.readLine();
             System.out.println(input);
             if(input.equals("true"))
                 break;
         }
        }catch(Exception E){}  
      }  
    });

    Thread write=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                output=in.nextLine();
                pw.println(output);
            }
       }   
    });
    public void start()throws Exception{
        s=new Socket("localhost",30000);
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        pw=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()),true);
        read.start();
        write.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c=new Client();
        try {
            c.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

**Server**

```
package FTP;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
    class Server{
        String input,output,path="D:/FTP/Server";
        private final String passwd="0000";
        ServerSocket ss;
        Socket s;
        BufferedReader br;
        PrintWriter pw;


        Thread read=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
           try{
                while(true){
                input=br.readLine();
              }
            }catch(Exception e){}
          }
        });
        Thread write=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                    while(true){
                    try {
                        pw.println("Enter Password");  
                     //while(br.readLine().isEmpty()){

                     //}

                     if(input.equals(passwd)){
                         pw.println("You Entered Magic Word");
                         pw.println("true");
                         break;
                     }  

                     else{
                         pw.println("Wrong Entry");
                         pw.flush();
                     }
                    } catch (Exception e) {} 
                    }  
               }

        });


        public void start() throws Exception{

            ss=new ServerSocket(30000);
            s=ss.accept();
            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            pw=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()),true);
            read.start();
            write.start();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Server s=new Server();
            try {
                s.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried using 
while(br.ready()) or while(br.readLine().isEmpty()) but am not able to make it wait

Answer (score 0):

try using while(br.readline()!=null)

Comment: Hi Its not solved the issue I have to give 2 input from Client side only then get response from Server that its wrong entry or magic word